# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_1: expected shape=(None, 50), found shape=(None, 52)

Tags: neural-network, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am getting a shape/value error. The neural network of my Language processing model is as follows:

```
## inputs
idx = layers.Input((50), dtype="int32", name="input_idx")
masks = layers.Input((50), dtype="int32", name="input_masks")
segments = layers.Input((50), dtype="int32", name="input_segments")
## pre-trained bert
nlp = transformers.TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
bert_out, _ = nlp([idx, masks, segments])
## fine-tuning
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(bert_out)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
date_out = layers.Dense(len(np.unique(date_train)), 
                     activation='softmax')(x)
## compile
model = models.Model([idx, masks, segments], date_out)
for layer in model.layers[:4]:
    layer.trainable = False
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

And the model's input shape is (None, 50).

model.summary() gives the following output:

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
    ==============================================================

====================================
input_idx (InputLayer)          [(None, 50)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_masks (InputLayer)        [(None, 50)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_segments (InputLayer)     [(None, 50)]         0              

                              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_bert_model_3 (TFBertModel)   ((None, 50, 768), (N 109482240   input_idx[0][0]                  
                                                                 input_masks[0][0]                
                                                                     input_segments[0][0]             
    ______________________________________________________________________________________

____________
    global_average_pooling1d_2 (Glo (None, 768)          0           tf_bert_model_3[0][0]            
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________

    dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 64)           49216       global_average_pooling1d_2[0][0] 
    
        

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 13770)        895050      dense_3[0][0]     

           
==================================================================================================
Total params: 110,426,506
Trainable params: 944,266
Non-trainable params: 109,482,240
_______________________________________________________________________________________
```

The code for model fitting is:

```
## encode y
dic_y_mapping = {n:label for n,label in 
                 enumerate(np.unique(date_train))}
inverse_dic = {v:k for k,v in dic_y_mapping.items()}
date_train = np.array([inverse_dic[date] for date in date_train])
## train
training = model.fit(x=X_train, y=date_train, batch_size=64, 
                     epochs=1, shuffle=True, verbose=1, 
                         validation_split=0.3)

## test
predicted_prob = model.predict(X_test)
predicted = [dic_y_mapping[np.argmax(pred)] for pred in predicted_prob]
```

While executing, I'm facing the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_1: expected shape=(None, 50), found shape=(None, 52)
```

Could someone please help sort this issue out?

Comment: If the starting point of this code was a tutorial, or an example in documentation, it can be helpful to give a link to it. Especially when you are not giving all your code or data, it can be helpful background. Also, is this using spaCy? If so, that would be a good tag to add.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that the input to the model has dimension 52 instead of 50. Looking at your code, that would be what you give to `model.fit()` as `x`, i.e. `X_train`.

So, either change the dimension of `X_train` to be 50. Or change the 50s in your model definition to be 52.

Aside: Do you use 50 because you have a 50 word vocabulary? The extra 2 could be special codes, such as UNK, EOS, etc.